# 16進数1b5b366e(※)を標準出力に書き込むと不可解な現象が発生する　※ESCシーケンス6nか？

Tags: untagged

## 現象

16進数`1b5b366e` (`^[`[6n)※を標準出力に書き込むと`echo`が終了し、あたかも`;1R`をキー入力したかのような状態となります。
　※`^[`は制御コードESCです。
簡単に確認できるよう`echo`コマンドを使用していますが、16進数`1b5b366e`が含まれるファイルを`cat`コマンドで標準出力に書き込んでも同じ現象が発生します。

```sh
$ echo -n -e "\x1b\x5b\x36\x6e"
$ ;1R
```

## 質問

1. どうしてこのような現象が発生するのか
2. 16進数`1b5b366e`は何なのか

## 経緯

`script`コマンドを起動し、`vim`を操作ました。結果ファイル`typescript`を`cat`コマンドで標準出力に書き込んだところ、同様の現象が発生しました。
原因を調べるため、現象が発生しない部分を除いていったところ、この16進数にたどり着きました。

## 環境

Ubuntu-18.04　(WSL)

Comment: [ANSI/VT100 Terminal Control](http://www.termsys.demon.co.uk/vtansi.htm) から `Query Cursor Position <ESC>[6n : Requests a Report Cursor Position response from the device.` それと、[Reading the Device Status Report ANSI escape sequence reply](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16026858/reading-the-device-status-report-ansi-escape-sequence-reply) が参考になるかと思います。

Comment: metropolis さん、早速のコメントありがとうございます。質問２がまだ謎なので、ヒントがないか調べてみます。端末のエミュレータ実装の問題かもしれませんが、標準出力した内容がどうしてshの入力になるのか？(;1Rはキー入力のエコーバックのようです、質問には書きませんでしたが、リーンキーを押下すると;1Rにshが反応します。)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

より厳密にいうと「標準出力」ではなくて「コンソール画面」それも [`vt100` 系エスケープシーケンス](https://www.google.com/search?q=vt100%20%E3%82%A8%E3%82%B9%E3%82%B1%E3%83%BC%E3%83%97)に対応している端末に出力した場合ですね。

「 `vt100` 端末」は画面制御にエスケープシーケンスを使っています。 `teraterm` のような端末ソフトも `vt100` エスケープシーケンスに対応しているくらい今でも一般的によく使われている画面制御手順です。別の例

```
$ echo -n -e "\x1b[2J" > clearscreen.txt
$ od -tx1 clearscreen.txt
0000000 1b 5b 32 4a　(標準出力をリダイレクトすると化けないことがわかる)
0000004
$ cat clearscreen.txt (画面が消去される）
$ echo -e "\x1b#8" (画面が E で埋まる)
```

`1b5b366e` はアスキー化すると `ESC[6n` です。これは端末情報のレポート機能で `vt100` はこのバイト列を受け取ると、カーソル位置を `ESC[数値１;数値２R` の形式でバイト列として返してきます。通常は interactive shell がそのバイト列を受け取るわけですが、シェルから見るとユーザーがキー入力したのか端末が生成したのかは区別ができず、つまりあたかもキー入力があったかのように見えることになります。で、最初の `ESC` キー入力は `bash` 等が行制御コマンドとして受け取るので画面上出力されず、よって `0;1R` のようなキー入力が行途中まであったかのように振る舞います。

`vi` や `vim` や `emacs` などスクリーンエディタはコンソール画面操作にこのエスケープシーケンスを使っています（厳密には `tcsetattr()` 等の端末制御関数が環境変数 `TERM=` に合わせてエスケープシーケンスを出力します）

`script` コマンドは画面を操作しないコマンド向けで `vi` のようなインタラクティブなコマンドのログを取るときは注意、とあります。実際、この質問においては画面制御コマンドまでログが取れてしまっていて混乱を招いています。あなたの目的に `script` コマンドが適切かどうかを再検討すべきでしょう。
https://linuxjm.osdn.jp/html/util-linux/man1/script.1.html

Comment: 774RRさん、コメントありがとうございます。知りたかったのはこれです。→「通常は interactive shell がそのバイト列を受け取るわけですが、シェルから見るとユーザーがキー入力したのか端末が生成したのかは区別ができず、つまりあたかもキー入力があったかのように見えることになります。」

Answer (score 0):

> 2. 16進数1b5b366eは何なのか

既にコメントがついているように、VT100互換のエスケープシーケンスです。
`ESC [ 6n` => `CSI 6n` で現在のカーソル位置の報告です。
`CSI y ; x R` の形式らしいですが、`CSI`で始まっているので、同様にエスケープシーケンスになるのでは?

Comment: greenteaさん、回答ありがとうございます。少しづつ分かってきたような気がします。vimがttyに書き込んだもののようですね。エスケープシーケンスを書き込むときんは何らかの処理が必要で、その処理はttyに書き込むようなものではなさそうです。